# Перенос базы данных с одного сервера на другой

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, сервер

Старый сервер сгорел. Я перенёс свой сайт на новый сервер, но как мне перенести его БД на новый сервер?

Старый сервер:
Raspberian
Raspberry Pi 4 8GB

Новый сервер:
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
MacPro 2014 For Servers

Сайт сделан на WordPress

Я пробовал просто скопировать файлы mysql с предыдущего сервера на новый, но всё равно не работает

Результат можете увидеть здесь: http://dmitry-yevseyev.tk

Comment: Копирование файлов - мало. Во-первых, на новом сервере нужно установить MySQL строго той же версии, причём в те же каталоги. Во-вторых, нужно скопировать весь `datadir` и положить вместо текущего (само собой, при выгруженном демоне сервера), а также файл конфигурации (который обычно лежит за пределами datadir).

Comment: где брать `datadir`?

Comment: @Akina и там стояла MariaDB, а на новом MySql

Comment: *где брать datadir?* В конфигурационном файле старого сервера. Причём их может быть несколько - надо найти тот, который реально использовался. Заодно учесть, что некоторые параметры (включая используемый конфиг и datadir) могли задаваться в строке запуска. *там стояла MariaDB, а на новом MySql* Значит. сносим MySQL, ставим MariaDB. Как уже было сказано - строго той же версии.